# Retrieve old database to new wamp phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

When i was going to install new wamp , i renamed wamp to wamp-backup . Is there any way to recover my old databases to new wamp server ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do is:

1. Run old phpmyadmin(old wamp)
2. Export all databases to .sql files
3. Turn this old wamp off and run new wamp
4. Import all databases in this phpmyadmin using that same .sql file.

Alternate but prone to errors could be:
Copy all the content from `wamp-backup\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.11\data` to `wampp-new\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.11\data`. This should also transfer the databases. Keep in mind your MySQL version folder could be different.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow this steps to restore the databases from old WAMP to new one

1. Backup all the databases (.sql file) using export feature of phpmyadmin
2. Install the fresh WAMP
3. Restore the all the databases(.sql file) using phpmyadmin Import Feature.

If you have already installed the new one without exporting the database then copy ibdata file (wamp-backup\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data) from backup to new one.
If it works then good otherwise replace your new wamp with old one and export databases then import them in new wamp.